# Finding the area of sectors of an ellipse

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections, polar-coordinates

How do I integrate the following polar integral? I'm not sure if it is possible.
$$ 0.5 \int\left( \frac{17.737 (1 - 0.967^2) }{1+0.967 \cos \theta}\right)^2 d \theta $$
or the general case:
$$ 0.5 \int\left( \frac{a (1 - e^2) }{1+e \cos \theta}\right)^2 d \theta $$
Where $0<e<1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you use $t=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$ substitution to turn it into a partial fraction integration?

Comment: Note that the numerator is a constant and can thus be placed in front of the integral.

Comment: The trick for integrating the area of an ellipse is that an ellipse is just a circle that has been rescaled in only one direction, and the impact of the scaling on area is simple: it multiplies the area by the scaling factor. This scaling also carries lines to lines, so the sides of your sector become radii of the circle, and the area of a sector of a circle is easy to find.